# Scroll to the results after results loaded by pressing a button

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website in Laravel. I am trying to modify a button so it scrolls down to the result section once they are loaded. I added this to the button

`<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" onClick="document.getElementById('acco').scrollIntoView();">Book now</button>`

But the problem is that it goes to the correct div, then the results loads and it scrolls back up to the "book now" section. [Here is the website if needed.](http://www.sundowners.ph)

Thanks for your help

Comment: The results are not ajax loaded. The page is totally redirecting to the new address.

Comment: So what should i add, not too sure how to do this. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You current page is not loading the results using an ajax request. So the whole page is redirected to the target (self redirecting) and the scroll goes to up when the page is refreshed. The simplest solution for this structure is to set the target of form pointing to the desired element so after the redirection, the scroll jumps to the target anchor:

```
<form action="?#acco">
```

The professional solution is to load the results using an ajax call without redirecting to a new address. This is the simple structure of Ajax call. for more details you have to read about [Jquery ajax method](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_ajax.asp):

```
<button onClick="loadResults()">Book now</button>

<script>
function loadResults(){
   var chekin=$("input[name:'checkin']).val();
   var checkout=$("input[name:'checkout']).val();
   $.ajax({
        url: "resultGenerator.php", //THE URL OF PAGE THAT RETURNS THE RESULTS IN PURE HTML FORMAT
        data: {"checkin":checkout,"checkout":checkout},
        success: function(result){
                 $("#acco").html(result);
                 document.getElementById('acco').scrollIntoView();
                }
    })
}
</script>
```

Comment: Ok thank you for your detailed answer. So can i do this ?
    '<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" action="?acco">Book now</button>'

Comment: Do not forget # sign `action="?#acco"`

Comment: Thank you, i did as you suggest, you can check on the live page, but it does not work.

Comment: I can not see the changes. The form has no `action` attribute yet. @HubertMuda

Comment: I thought that was what i did by adding this '<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" action="?#acco">Book now</button>' is that not what i was suppose to do ?

Comment: No. Action is an attribute for `form` element. Please check my answer above for correct usage. @HubertMuda

Comment: ok i see, but my "book now" is a button. How can i use this attribute in a button ? Can i make a book now button using a form ?

Comment: The button book now is already in a  `<form>` tag. Please search the source of page for `<form>` and you will find it.